# Expo startLocationUpdates throws IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have an Bare Expo app and I receive crash reports on Google Play Console:

```
Exception java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient' appears in base.apk!classes2.dex)
  at expo.modules.location.taskConsumers.LocationTaskConsumer.startLocationUpdates (LocationTaskConsumer.java:189)
  at expo.modules.location.taskConsumers.LocationTaskConsumer.didRegister (LocationTaskConsumer.java:73)
  at expo.modules.taskManager.TaskService.internalRegisterTask (TaskService.java:469)
  at expo.modules.taskManager.TaskService.restoreTasks (TaskService.java:565)
  at expo.modules.taskManager.TaskService.<init> (TaskService.java:78)
  at expo.modules.taskManager.TaskBroadcastReceiver.onReceive (TaskBroadcastReceiver.java:13)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4478)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:301)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2169)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8625)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Nowhere in my code I call `startLocationUpdates`, so that must be something internal.

I do not know where to keep looking. I have put a lot of try catches around every location-related piece of code, but no results.

Help and insights are appreciated.

Environmental info:

```
  expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.22621
    Binaries:
      Node: 16.13.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
      npm: 8.7.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^48.0.19 => 48.0.19 
      react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
      react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
      react-native: 0.71.8 => 0.71.8
    Expo Workflow: bare
```

```json
package.json
{
  "name": "mobile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {...},
  "resolutions": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~6.0.0",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "~6.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~6.0.0",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.4.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.1.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.11",
    "@sentry/react-native": "4.15.2",
    "crypto-es": "^1.2.7",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "expo": "^48.0.19",
    "expo-application": "~5.1.1",
    "expo-asset": "~8.9.1",
    "expo-av": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-battery": "~7.1.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.2.2",
    "expo-image": "~1.2.1",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-localization": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
    "expo-modules-autolinking": "~1.1.0 || ~1.2.0",
    "expo-network": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-task-manager": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "geolib": "^3.3.3",
    "i18next": "^19.8.4",
    "i18next-icu": "^1.4.2",
    "immutable": "^4.1.0",
    "intl-messageformat": "^10.2.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.14",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.7.3",
    "react-is": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-paper": "5.0.0-rc.10",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^1.3.5",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.27",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.25.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.1",
    "reselect": "^4.1.7",
    "sentry-expo": "~6.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "eslint": "^8.46.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^10.1.0",
    "glob": "^8.0.3",
    "replace-in-file": "^6.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```